# How can I match two torn edges?

Tags: opencv, contour

[Link to Gist of code.](https://gist.github.com/smeschke/aa989df78551a9050a78e0d7a8c50495) I am trying to reconstruct a torn paper. The first step is to detect the torn edge:

[image: finding the torn edge]

Next, one torn edge is rotated and compared to the other torn edge:

[image: rotating and matching]

The document is aligned when the two contours match each other. One piece is rotated and the torn edges are compared. A score called `match` describes the match between the two contours:

```
tempA = draw_contour(tempA, b, 123, 3)
tempB = draw_contour(tempB, a, 123, 3)
tempC = tempA + tempB
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(tempC, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
thresh = 255 - thresh
match = sum(sum(thresh))
```

These two contours don't fit together well:
[image: poor fitting]
These contours fit together very well. Here the document is aligned:
[image: good fitting]

Calculation of the contour matching is basic. I draw the contours on separate images. The images are summed and a threshold applied. This counts the number of pixels where the two contours overlap. This method works well, but it's too slow to be practical when comparing several edges.

## How can I calculate how well the two contours of the torn edges match?

Comment: Are the two torn pieces in the same image? If they are not, one torn edge will in general be a perspective transformation of the other. If they are two different images, do you guarantee that the transformation is an isometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no complications (see my comment above), you can try the procedure outlined below. See the following figure.

[image: edges]

- calculate the straight line equation that joins the endpoints of the edge1
- calculate the straight line equation that joins the endpoints of the edge2
- calculate the angle between the these two straight lines
- this gives you two possibilities for the angle: `alpha` or `180-alpha`
- find the midpoints of the two straight line segments and align them (not shown in the figure. may be you are already doing something to align the curves)
- then, try the two angles and see which one gives the best match according to your matching cost